# Android Navigation Component navigate to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I am using Navigation Component to navigate through pages in my app.

I have a ProfileFragment and users might navigate to this fragment from different fragments(like HomeFragment, ArticleFragment, and ...).

In my ProfileFragment how should I know where to navigate the user to the previous page before they opened Profile. When the user pressed Back Button how am I supposed to detect the right action.

In my fragment's toolbar, I have an arrow (ImageButton) for navigation to the previous page too. How should I handle it in its onClickListener?

[Here you can see the graph of my navigation.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMg7g.png)

Comment: When you will press the back button the app will load the previous fragment automatically. You will not have to do anything.

Comment: Check out my update question please

Answer (score 1):

When user clicks the back arrow in the Toolbar, you can call `findNavController().popBackStack()`. This will move user to the last fragment in the back stack, regardless of which one was visible before (before moving to ProfileFragment).